I am seeking a 1970's short story about a lone survivor/explorer on a distant planet exploring a long deserted stone city
I am looking for a 1970's short scifi story from a magazine where a lone astronaut/explorer is stranded/ on an alien world in a deserted alien stone city. The city's replicators try and make food and water for him but it makes him sick, yet he continues to try. After awhile, one day, the city gets it right and he can keep down the food and water it gives him. He goes out on the terrace to bask in the sun and sees himself in a reflection and sees that he has turned into a sentient lizard, the implication being that the AI city could not figure out how to make food to feed him, but it could change him into one of the now extinct inhabitants instead.   He described the first attempts of the AI to make food as "greasy gruel", and he could give it samples of crumbs he had, from whence it tried to make food.
This has bugged me for decades, what is this story?

This question is similar to: Short story pre-1978 astronaut? stranded in deserted city, saved by stone that gives up water. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DoscoJones - Our policy is to not close questions as duplicates until we have confirmation from both.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

As per Dosco Jones's suggestion, and SF Story about human adapting to alien environment, this might be A.E. van Vogt's Enchanted Village, originally published in Other Worlds Science Stories in 1950, also published under the titles The Sands of Mars and The Enchanted Village.
As per your description, what it initially releases does look like gruel (and gives him chemical burns when he touches it), but after he sacrifices a few crumbs of remaining rations, it produces edible food. He eventually realizes that the village can't provide food actually nutritious to him and he grows more ill, until he wakes up one morning and finds that that trough has food that is delicious and nourishes him completely. Unable to provide for him, it has instead changed him to a form that it can help.

"I've won!" thought Jenner. "The village has found a way!"
After a while he remembered something and crawled to the bathroom. Cautiously, watching the ceiling, he eased himself backward into the shower stall. The yellowish spray came down, cool and delightful.
Ecstatically Jenner wriggled his four-foot tail and lifted his long snout to let the thin streams of liquid wash away the food impurities that clung to his sharp teeth.
Then he waddled out to bask in the sun and listen to the timeless music.

